# Angular - translating DIV titles in IE11

Tags: internet-explorer-11, angular-translate

I am using Angular-translate to make my application multi lingual. I am having a problem with translating a title attribute on DIV element. Here is code I am using:

```
<div title="{{ 'Details' | translate }}" style="padding-top:10px;padding-left:5px">
```

It works fine in Chrome, but in IE it shows {{ 'Details' | translate }}. Any idea what might be wrong?